# Selenium find specific link out of multiple same named links

Tags: selenium

so the situation is I have a bunch of posts in a column with a message and a delete link next to each message (the message and link share an element). I want to be able to match the text of the message with a predetermined text, then have Selenium click the delete link next to that post's message. Is this possible?

```
<ul class="announcements unread">
<li>
    <div class="announcement-text">Test message
    <a href="edit/231">Edit</a> <a href="delete/231">Delete</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="announcement-text">Delete this message
    <a href="edit/232">Edit</a> <a href="delete/232">Delete</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

The number behind the edit and delete in the link is like an id for that message

Comment: Please add the HTML.  What you're describing is likely very possible using xpath.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack overflow. As @Richard has pointed out - it's hard to help you without you giving us some representative HTML for us to look at. So if you can - please edit your question and give us just a little more to work with. Otherwise we'll be forced to give you an equally vague answer, like "just choose the right one with xpath" ;) Here's a guide to how to write a good example case http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

That sounds pretty much possible.

Your post seems to look like

```
<Element>
    <Message> some message text </Message>
    <DeleteLink/>
</Element>
```

So, you would simply have to loop over each of the posts, match the message text, and click the delete link if a match is found.

Answer (score 0):

As **bit** said, you can loop over each of the posts doing :

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".element .message"));

for(int i = 0 ; i< list.size() ; i++){
    String message = list.get(i).getText();
    if(message.contains("whatever_you_want"){
        // Here you click on the corresponding delete link
        driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".element .deleteLink")).get(i).click();
    }
}
```

Note that as I don't know how your HTML looks like, I've taken class names for css Selectors, based on **bit** answer